# How to show footer from index.html to all html pages using tags and filters?

Tags: html, django, django-rest-framework, django-templates

if I have **index.html** and it contains many plugins like a search box, posts , comment section, etc ... and I just want to take the **Footer section** and add it to all of my html pages using tags and filters , to edit it easy in all html page in future , can i do this ?

this is my footer code in index.html :

```
<footer style="margin:auto" class="py-5 bg-dark h-50 d-inline-block w-100 p-3">
<div class="container">

<div class="text-center mt-4">
          
     <a href="/Privacy_Policy" style="margin:5px;width:140px" role="presentation" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg">Privcy Policy</a>
     
     <a href="/request_apps/" style="margin:5px;width:140px" role="presentation" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg">Request apps</a> 
     
     <a href="/our_Mission" style="margin:5px;width:140px" role="presentation" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg">Our Mission</a>
  
     <a href="/Contact_US" style="margin:5px;width:140px" role="presentation" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg">Contact us</a>
     
      <a href="/About_Me" style="margin:5px;width:140px" role="presentation" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg">About us</a>

</div>

<!-- copyright -->
  <p style="font-family:monospace;font-size:18px" class="m-0 text-center text-white" >Copyright 2019-2020 SoftDLR.com All Rights Reserved. </p>
</div>
<!-- /.container -->
```

Comment: Are you using a base HTML template which you extend for other views?

Comment: no , i don't @Ryan

Comment: That's what you need. @João Haas answer shows you how.

Comment: thanks for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the way @João Haas recommended above works wonderfully, there is another which I personally use, although I don't think either is technically better than the other, that is setting the footer as its own, separate snippet. I personally find this to be cleaner looking to read and edit.

```
<!-- base.html -->
    <html>
      <head>
          <!-- stuff you want every page to have on the head -->
          <!-- head block for extending -->
          {% block head %}
          {% endblock %}
        </head>
        <body>
          <!-- body block for extending -->
          {% include 'snippets/base_css.html' %}
          {% include 'snippets/header.html' %}
          {% block body %}
          {% endblock %}
          <!-- your footer html -->
          {% include 'snippets/footer.html' %}
      </html>

<!-- snippets/footer.html -->
<footer class="container">
    <p> footer info </p>
</footer>

<!-- snippets/header.html -->
<div class="container">
    <p>Header info</p>
</div>
```

To do this set up a templates directory in your main dir and then a sub-directory just for snippets. the structure would look something like this:

```
manage.py
templates
----base.html
----snippets
    ----base_css.html
    ----header.html
    ----footer.html
    ----other_snippet.html
    ----another_snippet.html
    ----and_another_snippet.html
```

honestly, the more the merrier, I use these things like crazy. They make life a million times easier when the code gets increasingly complex.

Comment: thanks bro really ,, just a few qustion , i must create footer.html first then add my style then i use  {% include 'snippets/footer.html' %} in any page right ??

Comment: no worries man, ill add to my answer above to help describe that process

Comment: thanks a loooot bro you saved me , i'm waiting you thanks

Comment: no worries man, if the answer worked for you always remember you can upvote and accept, if not, let me know what I can do to help more

Comment: hello can you help me with this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63764870/exception-type-nameerror-at-exception-value-name-pcgames-is-not-defined-in?noredirect=1#comment112757824_63764870]

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to have a base HTML file with multiple blocks, and create other pages extending from it:

```html
<!-- base.html -->
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- stuff you want every page to have on the head -->
    <style>
      * {
        font-size: 14;
      }
    </style>
    <!-- head block for extending -->
    {% block head %}
    {% endblock %}
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- body block for extending -->
    {% block body %}
    {% endblock %}
    <!-- your footer html -->
    <footer>
      ...
    </footer>
</html>
```

You would then create all files like this:

```html
<!-- page.html -->
{% extends "base.html" %}

<!-- page specific head -->
{% block head %}
<style>
  div {
    margin: 0;
  }
</style>
{% endblock %}

<!-- page specific body -->
{% block body %}
<p>The footer should be added after this paragraph!</p>
{% endblock %}
```

The idea of extending with blocks is that whenever you ask for `page.html`, it will use `base.html` with the block definitions you created on `page.html`. If a block is not defined, it will simply not be rendered on the final html.

Comment: thhhhhannnkss a loooot bro ,,, thanks very much ,,, i was found Bush Muncher way easy more than your way , but your way very helpful really it will help me a lot , thanks

Comment: Yeah, indeed Bush's approach may work better depending on the size of the project