# Exception Type: NameError at / Exception Value: name 'pcgames' is not defined in django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

hello i tried to make pagination

i have problem when i try to add pagination to my home html page , i tried this in my code but i got error ..

i tried do this :

views.py :

```
def home_page(request, template='html_file/enterface.html'):
    contextt = {
        'opratingSystems': OpratingSystems.objects.all(),
        'androidgames': AndroidGames.objects.all(),
        'androidapk': AndroidApks.objects.all(),
        'antivirus': Antivirus.objects.all(),
        'pcgames': PCgames.objects.all(),
        'pcprogram': PCprogram.objects.all(),
    }

    app = pcgames.objects.all()
    page = request.GET.get('Page', 1) # the_home_page is the name of pages when user go to page 2 etc
    paginator = Paginator(app, 6) # 6 that's mean it will show 6 apps in page
    try:
        pcgame = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        pcgame = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
    pcgame = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return render(request,template,contextt)
```

in HTML page :

```
       <div class="container">
    <div class='row'>


        {% for pcgame in pcgames %}
        <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 website-thumb'>
            
            <a href=" {{ pcgame.page_url }} ">
          
            <img src="{{ pcgame.get_image }}" class='image_control_for_home_page_pc_games' alt=''> </a>
            
            <h3 class="font_control_for_home_page_pc_games_name"><a href=" {{ pcgame.page_url }} ">{{     pcgame.name }}</a></h3>


    </div>
     {% endfor %}
</div>

      {% if pcgame.has_previous %}
<a id="border_pagination" class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?Page=1">First</a>
<a id="border_pagination" class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?Page={{     pcgame.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a>
  {% endif %}

  {% for num in pcgame.paginator.page_range %}
    {% if pcgame.number == num %}
      <a class="btn btn-info mb-4" href="?Page={{ num }}">{{ num }}</a>
    {% elif num > pcgame.number|add:'-5' and num < pcgame.number|add:'6' %}
      <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?Page={{ num }}">{{ num }}</a>
    {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}

  {% if pcgame.has_next %}
    <a id="border_pagination" class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?Page={{ pcgame.next_page_number     }}">Next</a>
    <a id="border_pagination" class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?Page={{     pcgame.paginator.num_pages     }}">Last</a>
  {% endif %}
```

and i got this error :

```
File "/home/mysite/django/first_app/views.py" in home_page
line 38.     app = pcgames.objects.all()
Exception Type: NameError at /
Exception Value: name 'pcgames' is not defined
```

any help please , i want to show 6 item per page

Comment: well, you didn't import pcgames...

Comment: ohh yes i can see that , but how i can import import and use it  please

Comment: You don't. Look 4 lines above and think about uppercase versus lowercase.

Comment: i can't see the wrong ,, do you mean 'pcgames' must be 'PCgames' ?

Comment: Change to `app = PCgames.objects.all()`.

Comment: ahh ok thanks a lot i will try it and tell you

Comment: i added what u say but nothing happens ! 
no pagination and the page show all games

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221063/discussion-between-kok-hyvv-and-melvyn).